# Trying to understand Kitaev's calculation of relative Majorana number in two dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, spin-models

In appendix C.4.3 of "Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond", Kitaev provides a proof of the fact that when the Chern number is odd, a vortex in the gauge field accompanies an unpaired majorana mode.

The original gauge configuration that appears in the quadratic hamiltonian of majorana operators is B, while the one with a vortex is B'. He tries to prove the relative majorana number of them is $(-1)^{\nu(P)}$ where $P=\frac{1}{2}(1-iB)$ is the spectral projector and $\nu(P)$ is its Chern number. He defines the projection operator to x>0 plane and y>0 plane to be $\Pi^{(x)}$ and $\Pi^{(y)}$ respectively, and defines $X=i(P\Pi^{(x)}P+(1-P)\Pi^{(x)}(1-P))$. Then he express the relative majorana number as
$$M(B,B')=\det(e^{-\pi X}e^{-i\pi\Pi^{(y)}} e^{\pi X}e^{i\pi\Pi^{(y)}})=\exp(i\pi^2Tr[X,\Pi^{(y)}])$$

I'm having a hard time understanding the second equality, this does look like Glauber's formula, but based on my present understanding $[X,\Pi^{(y)}]$ doesn't necessarily commute with X and $\Pi^{(y)}$. I've tried writing a full expansion analogue of Glauber's formula, but can't prove the trace of higher order terms are necessarily zero.

What's more difficult to understand is in the next line, while calculating $Tr[X,\Pi^{(y)}]$, he seems to claim $Tr(P^2[X,\Pi^{(y)}])=Tr(P[X,\Pi^{(y)}]P)$. To my understanding, these are all infinite dimensional matrices and I can't see why the cyclic property of trace can be used. After all, this is the point of taking the trace of a commutator.

I wish someone having more familiarities with this work can give me some hints.

Comment: I just realized this was mentioned in equation (134), but I still don't know how to prove it.